# Tcolorbox rule width with table inside

Tags: tcolorbox

Apparently, the `boxrule` command has not effect with an enhanced `tcolorbox` having a tabularx inside.

How can I specify the width of the frame arount the tabularx ?

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

% \usepackage{array,tabularx}
% \usepackage{colortbl} - or - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\tcbset{enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=red!30!white,
    coltitle=black,center title,
    boxrule=10pt, % NO EFFECT
}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0.5mm}{X|X|X},title=My table]
    One
    & Two
    & Three \\\hline\hline
    1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00\\\hline
    2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00
\end{tcolorbox}

% EDIT : with a multicolumn as 1st cell this does not compile anymore
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=2pt,tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth2pt}{YY|YY|YY},
    title=My table
    ]
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{title}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{title}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{title} \\\hline
    2 & d & 3 & e & 4 & f \\\hline
    title & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{h} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{title} & j \\
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT :** the first answer is alright for the 1st table in the MWE, but I'm using a `multicolumn` as 1st cell and this brings an `Misplaces \omit` error. MWE has been modified with the problematic table.

Comment: Should be possible to set it for individual boxes; would it be sufficient or not?

Comment: In the modified MWE, tabular column `Y` is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of the `tabularx` style has as setting for the `boxrule` to be `0.5mm`. You can overwrite the setting by copying the style from the source and removing this part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

% \usepackage{array,tabularx}
% \usepackage{colortbl} - or - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\tcbset{enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=red!30!white,
    coltitle=black,center title,
    boxrule=10pt, % NO EFFECT
}
\makeatletter
\tcbset{tabularx*/.style 2 args={%
    boxsep=\z@,top=\z@,bottom=\z@,leftupper=\z@,rightupper=\z@,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,% boxrule setting here removed
    before upper={\arrayrulecolor{tcbcol@frame}\def\arraystretch{1.1}#1%
      \tcb@hack@currenvir\tabularx{\linewidth}{#2}},
    after upper=\endtabularx\arrayrulecolor{black}}}
\makeatother
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0.5mm}{X|X|X},title=My table]
    One
    & Two
    & Three \\\hline\hline
    1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00\\\hline
    2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Edit: in more recent versions of `tcolorbox` the definition is slightly changed. In that case the new definition should be as follows:

```
\tcbset{tabularx*/.style 2 args={%
    boxsep=\z@,top=\z@,bottom=\z@,leftupper=\z@,rightupper=\z@,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,
    before upper*={%
      \let\tcb@CT@arc@save\CT@arc@%
      \arrayrulecolor{tcbcolframe}\def\arraystretch{1.1}#1%
      \tcb@hack@currenvir\tabularx{\linewidth}{#2}},
    after upper*={\endtabularx\global\let\CT@arc@\tcb@CT@arc@save}%
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! However `tcbcol@frame` -> `tcbcolframe` to be able to compile the MWE ;)

Comment: This does not work when the 1st cell of the table is a multicolumn...
With this tcolorbox I get a `Misplaced \omit` due to the 1st multicolumn.
`\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=2pt,tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth2pt}{YY|YY|YY},
 title=My table
 ]
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{title}
 &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{title}
 &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{title} \\\hline
 2 & d & 3 & e & 4 & f \\\hline
 title & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{h} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{title} & j \\
\end{tcolorbox}`

Comment: @3isenHeim I get that error also without the redefinition of the tabular style, so that is a separate issue. You could ask a new question about it.

Comment: I don''t get the error when I remove the redefinition.

Comment: Then it is probably a version problem (I use a slightly older version of `tcolorbox`). The second part of the definition in the latest (4.31 2020/07/31) version is `before upper*={%
      \let\tcb@CT@arc@save\CT@arc@%
      \arrayrulecolor{tcbcolframe}\def\arraystretch{1.1}#1%
      \tcb@hack@currenvir\tabularx{\linewidth}{#2}},
    after upper*={\endtabularx\global\let\CT@arc@\tcb@CT@arc@save}%`, note the `*` at before and after upper, `tcbcolframe` without `@`, and the parts about `CT@arc` that are not present in my version.

Comment: You can check if the more modern version works, if it does I will add it to the answer (or you can add it yourself by editing my answer).

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If the need is to change value of `boxrule` specified by option `tabularx*`, then `tabularx*/.append style={boxrule=<dimen>}` is simpler, in which`.append style` is one of predefined `pgfkeys` handlers.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    colframe=red!50!black,
    colbacktitle=red!30!white,
    coltitle=black,
    center title,
    % change boxrule set by "tabularx*", by default it's 0.5mm
    tabularx*/.append style={boxrule=10pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0.5mm}{X|X|X}, title=My table]
    One
    & Two
    & Three \\\hline\hline
    1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00\\\hline
    2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update

Just for fun. Here a new `pgfkeys` handler `.patch code={<search>}{<replace>}` which internally used `\xpatchcmd` from `xpatch` package, is defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\makeatletter
% usage:
%   <key>/.patch code={search}{replace}
% similar to def of /handlers/.add code/.code 2 args={...}
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.patch/.code 2 args=%
  % Find out, whether with args or not.
  \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@args}%
  {% Yes, so add to body and reuse args
    \pgfkeyspatchvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@body}{#1}{#2}%
    % Redefine code
    {%
      \pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@args}{\pgfkeys@tempargs}%
      \pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@body}{\pgfkeys@tempbody}%
      \def\pgfkeys@marshal{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\pgfkeys@global@temp\pgfkeys@tempargs}%
      \expandafter\pgfkeys@marshal\expandafter{\pgfkeys@tempbody}%
    }%
    \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@@body}{%
      % support for \pgfkeysndefargs:
      \pgfkeyslet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@@body}{\pgfkeys@global@temp}%
    }{%
      % support for \pgfkeysdefargs:
      \pgfkeyslet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{\pgfkeys@global@temp}%
    }%
  }{% No, so single argument (simple \pgfkeysdef). Redefine accordingly.
    \edef\pgf@expanded@path{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
    {%
      \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgf@expanded@path/.@cmd}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pgfkeys@temptoks
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \csname pgfk@\pgf@expanded@path/.@body\endcsname}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\pgfkeys@temptoks\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\pgfkeyssetvalue\expandafter{\pgf@expanded@path}{##1}}%
      }%
      \edef\pgfkeys@temp{\the\pgfkeys@temptoks}%
      \pgfkeyspatchvalue\pgfkeys@temp{#1}{#2}%
      \global\let\pgfkeys@global@temp\pgfkeys@temp
    }%
    \def\pgf@temp{\pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgf@expanded@path/.@body}}%
    \expandafter\pgf@temp\expandafter{\pgfkeys@global@temp}%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfkeys@temp\expandafter##\expandafter1\expandafter\pgfeov\expandafter{\pgfkeys@global@temp}%
    \pgfkeyslet{\pgf@expanded@path/.@cmd}\pgfkeys@temp
  }%  
}

% usage:
%   \pgfkeyspatchvalue{<key>}{<search>}{<replace>}
% similar to \pgfkeysaddvalue
\long\def\pgfkeyspatchvalue#1#2#3{%
  \pgfkeysifdefined{#1}{%
    \expandafter\xpatchcmd\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}{}
      {\PackageError{pgfkeys}{Patching for key #1 fails}}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tcbset{
  colframe=black!25,
  colbacktitle=black!75
}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=5pt, tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0.5mm}{X|X|X}, title=Before patching]
  One     & Two     & Three   \\ \hline\hline
  1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\ \hline
  2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00
\end{tcolorbox}

% patch option "tabularx*", remove "boxrule=0.5mm"
\tcbset{
  tabularx*/.patch={boxrule=0.5mm}{}
}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=5pt, tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0.5mm}{X|X|X}, title=After patching]
  One     & Two     & Three   \\ \hline\hline
  1000.00 & 2000.00 & 3000.00 \\ \hline
  2000.00 & 3000.00 & 4000.00
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: example of new pgfkeys handler ".patch code"]

Comment: Thanks, but then it's hard-coded, and you loose the capacity of specifying it as you define the tcolorbox...

Comment: @3isenHeim Yes. I've added a new-`pgfkeys`-handler approach to my answer.